# SQL Select or Insert return ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Alright so a quick SQL question here(using sql-server-2008).

I have a mapping table `names` with the following columns

`ID` `DisplayName`

What I want to do is first 
`SELECT [ID] FROM [names] WHERE [DisplayName] = 'chuck';`

BUT, if the name 'chuck' doesn't exist in the database, I would like to create it, and return the auto incremented `ID`.

I was wondering if SQL had some built in way of doing this in an easy way, or if I have to go the long route?

long route being something like this

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) AS count, ID FROM names WHERE DisplayName='chuck'
IF(count > 0)
    SELECT ID as ReturnID;
ELSE
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO names(DisplayName) values('chuck');
    SELECT scope_identity() as ReturnID;
    END
```

I didn't test that last statement, but I assume the long way would be something like that. If there is no built in way, I'd appreciate it if someone could simply correct that statement(as I'm sure it isn't completely correct).

Comment: If only supporting 200*+, use the [MERGE syntax](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx)

Comment: Would you be able to provide an example? I'm trying to learn more advanced ways of using sql.

Comment: @kelton52: there are examples in the end of the article OMG Ponies linked. You need to scroll down a bit.

Comment: @zespri I saw the examples, but none of them were doing what I was trying to do. I looked through the examples but didn't understand them. Besides if he would have put his comment as an answer with an example I could have selected it.

Comment: @kelton52 It's the last one where `OUTPUT` is used, but this won't work in your case. It only works when there is a INSERT or UPDATE scenario. Otherwise the output would be empty when the record already exists.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should take care about transactions as well:

```
set XACT_ABORT on
begin tran

declare @ID int

select @ID = ID from names with (holdlock, updlock) WHERE DisplayName='chuck'

if @@rowcount = 0
begin
  INSERT INTO names(DisplayName) values('chuck');
  set @ID = scope_identity();
end

select @ID as ReturnID;

commit tran
```

Note the usage of table hints - **holdlock** and **updlock**. They prevent another thread from executing exactly the same query and creating the row a second time. For more information look for isolation, synchronization, deadlocks, concurrent updates.

Comment: Alright, so ran this and now the tables deadlocked...any ideas?

Comment: you also have from in there twice, assuming that wasn't intentional

Comment: also sql doesn't recognize the xac_abort

Comment: basically this query will work every time, but no other queries to the table will work.

Comment: ALso keep in mind, this query will be run from one script, not a website or anything...so there won't be multiple calls of this query at the same time..essentially it's just a perl script that will be inserting CSV values into the database

Comment: Sorry - I misspelled it - it's XACT_ABORT

Comment: This query can never dead lock. However if you run it twice on different connections (and threads) at the same time it's possible that both sees the record as non-existing and create a new record. Unless you have a unique constraint on the **DisplayName** column you will get two records.
This might not be possible in your case. However, I always ensure my queries are thread-safe.

Comment: And the query CAN dead-lock if transactions are used in a slightly different manner. For example if you do not specify the **updlock** then both queries can check if the row exists (thus holding a serializable and read lock on the table) and then when one of the queries tries to create a new row it will fail with a dead-lock.

Comment: alright cool...thanks, this seems to work...A bit more lengthy than I was hoping, but it seems like the most proper way to do what I wanted to do. I think I'm going to look into turning this into a stored procedure, as I have quite a few mapping tables that would benefit from this code. Thanks again.

Comment: If concurrency is not an issue you can of course remove the transactions and locks. However, the query is still a good example how to do get the ID and in the same time to check if a row exists.

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT null from names where DisplayName='Chuck'))
   INSERT INTO Names (DisplayName) Values ('Chuck')

SELECT ID as ReturnID FROM Names where DisplayName='Chuck'
```

Doesn't save much though

Comment: Isn't this at best executing 2 queries, and worst, executing 1 query?

Answer (score 0):

```
go
create table names
(
    Id int primary key identity(1,1),
    displayname varchar(100),
);

go
create procedure P1
    @displayname varchar(100)
as
    insert into names (displayname)
    select @displayname
    where not exists (
        select * from names, (select @displayname as displayname) as names2
            where names.displayname = names2.displayname);

    -- race condition is possible here,
    -- but in some cases you still may get away with this

    select id from names where displayname = @displayname;

go  
declare @dn varchar(100);

set @dn = 'chuck'; exec P1 @dn; exec P1 @dn; exec P1 @dn;

set @dn = 'buck'; exec P1 @dn; exec P1 @dn;

select * from names;

go
drop table names; drop procedure P1;
```

Output would `1, 1, 1, 2, 2` and the table content two rows big.